# Terminal cannot run shell script files stored in PATH directories

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, opensuse

Getting "command not found" when trying to run shell script file. The file itself is stored in a directory, that is added to PATH, but still, terminal doesn't recognize it as shell script.

Here's the sequence I try:

```
tajimura/GAMIT% echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/user/games:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/lib64/jvm/jre/bin:/home/tajimura/GAMIT/gamit/bin:/home/jaimura/GAMIT/kv/bin:/home/tajimura/GAMIT/com
tajirmura/GAMIT% ls /home/tajimura/GAMIT/com/sh_steup
/home/tajimura/GAMIT/com/sh_setup
tajimura/GAMIT% sh_setup
sh_setup: Command not found.
tajimura/GAMIT% sh sh_setup
sh: sh_setup: No such file or directory
tajimura/GAMIT% l /home/tajimura/GAMIT/com/sh_setup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tajimura users 11109 Aug 20   2013 /home/tajimura/GAMIT/com/sh_setup
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

PS: Opensuse 12.1 here.

ADDED: I was executing it just fine during first 4 days, so I guess hashbang is not an issue. But I can't guarantee that workstation wasn't rebooted between my sessions, so maybe (just may be) -noexec is the cause. However, script sits in my home directory on hard disk, it's not a removable drive.

ADDED: The first five lines of sh_setup:

```
    /home/tajimura% sed 5q /home/tajimura/GAMIT/com/sh_setup
    #!/bin/csh -f
    #
    #doc Check and setup the GAMIT tables directory
    #doc
    #
```

Comment: Do the folders `GAMIT` and `com` have required file system permissions?

Comment: 1. show us what sh_setup is

Comment: Pretty sure the `sh sh_setup` is failing because you aren't in `com`. The first one (just `sh_setup`) may be if `sh_setup` is a broken symlink.

Comment: The brutal error message indicates `(t)csh` is in use (other shells prefix the message with the shell, and give different messages). The highest probability is that the file system that `sh_setup` sits on is mounted with `noexec` (e.g. from a pendrive). if you do a `grep \`stat --format=%m /home/tajimura/GAMIT/com/sh_setup\` /proc/mounts`, you'll probably find a `noexec` in the line. do a `sudo mount -o remount,exec - <mountpoint>` and the file should be executable.

Comment: Show us the first 5 lines of your script (`sed 5q /home/tajimura/GAMIT/com/sh_setup`).  What changed between the time when it worked and the time when it stopped working?  Something changed, even if you don't know what yet, and tracking that down may be crucial.  Did you remove or rename anything?

Comment: Nothing removed or renamed. Yesterday I even reinstalled the whole GAMIT toolkit, however it doesn't help. I won't have acess to the workstation till Wednesday, so, for now I can't even check proposals made here.

Comment: Added first 5 lines of the script to original topic.

Comment: Your shell has no idea what `/home/tajimura%` is , so -> `command not found`

Comment: and how can i deal with that?

Comment: What are you trying to have `/home/tajimura%` do? Are you waning to change into the `/home/tajimura` directory? As it is, your shell is trying to execute it.

Comment: Hey, David, I have just realized, that you think, that /home/tajimura% is an entered sequence, but it is just a command line prompt, not an input.

Answer (score 2):

Your script <strike>is either not executable (make it so with `chmod +x sh_setup`) or it</strike> specifies a broken (non-existing) interpreter on its hash-bang line (the first line of the `sh_setup` file, starting with `#!`).

Your `sh sh_setup` invocation fails because it doesn't use `$PATH` and you're in the wrong directory.

EDIT: Your script is clearly executable (I didn't spot this in your screenshot at first), which leaves us with a possibly incorrect interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an unexpected solution of the problem. If I call the script under bash instead of csh everything is good.